# Using Semaphore in service inside a DeferredResult REST method in Spring Boot

Tags: java, rest, asynchronous, spring-boot

i have a code where i try tu use a DeferredResult in my REST controller method, my service uses an async method and try to use a Semaphore for restrict futures calls in that resource, when i use @Async the semaphore.acquire() throws an InterruptedException, if i call my semaphore directly in my REST method the acquire method never returns so the code hangs, here is my two cases:

Method from my service called from a DeferredResult REST Method in my controller:

```
    @Async
    public void myAsyncMethod( DeferredResult<Boolean> result) throws InterruptedException,
            ExecutionException {
        processRunning.acquire(); // my semaphore (Throws InterruptedException: null)
        ... // long process using RxJava in a thread pool and a countdownLatch for wait
        result.setResult(true);
    }
```

My DeferredResult method, i test using my @Async method getting the InterruptedException, then i test using a method that is not async and try to use the semaphore, but the code stops in the acquire() method and never continues:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myRestMethod",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public DeferredResult<Boolean> asyncRESTMethod() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException{
        DeferredResult<Boolean> result = new DeferredResult<Boolean>();
            myService.getProcessRunning().acquire(); // getting the semaphore and try to acquire, the code hangs here and not continue

            Thread tr = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        myService.myMethod();
                        result.setResult(true);
                    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            tr.start();
            tr.join();
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution, the problem was that in some point of my code i call from my semaphore the method tryAcquire that also acquires the semaphore but returns true or false, so when i try to acquire again the semaphore already not have empty slots so the code hangs or throws the interruptedException.